# Ensure python script isn't run as root

Tags: python, sudo

My first python program (hopefully finished in a thousand years) breaks if run as root, such as with `sudo`, due to `dbus` stuff. How can I ensure it wasn't called with `sudo` prefix or from root prompt `#` instead of regular user prompt `$`?

Answer (score 4):

Put this into your Python program/script:

```
#import os

if os.geteuid() == 0:
    exit("You cannot call 'mmm' using using 'sudo' powers. Exiting.")
```

Of course you would replace `mmm` with your own python filename.

Comment: You could use `sys.argv[0]` (basenamed, if you wish) and avoid hardcoding `mmm`.

Comment: @Amadan Oh so very true. I do similar thing in my many bash scripts using `$0`. However since I'm still on my first Python program (for two months *sigh*) it was overkill for me :)

Comment: wait a minute.. I see the same user asking then answering the question?

Comment: @todd--[User can answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  Apparently it's even encouraged (for good questions).

Comment: @Todd Actually first I searched for the answer. Couldn't find the answer but found the opposite question with answer so divined and posted a self answered question to help others in my situation.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix do we get points for that.. effort to be helpful? =)

Comment: @Todd Simple questions like this will get points, but the other I wrote tonight is so complicated it will probably garner none: [Cannot trap some Python DBus except errors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566868/cannot-trap-some-python-dbus-except-errors/568395#568395)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix oh cool. I've had several occasions where I couldn't find the answer here and eventually got to an answer that others could have used. I'll have to post next time that happens.